# Let State update before running async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a useFetch hook. If the fetchData function is called again while the data is pending the `controller.abort()` is called and the function reruns. The only issue is that React is not updating the dispatch functions fast enough. How can I make it so that when the `controller.abort()` function is called, It will wait until all the state changes have been made before re-running the `fetchData` function. I took a shot at it with useEffect but cannot get it to work. Thanks!

```
 export const useFetchStats = (callNumber: number, params?: any) => {
  const { statsDispatch } = useAppState();
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState<any>(null);
  const [isLoading] = useState(false);

  const newUrl = new URL(`${process.env.REACT_APP_STATS_ENDPOINT}${statsCalls[callNumber].url}`
  );


  const dispatch: any = statsCalls[callNumber].type;
  let controller: any = null;

  const fetchData = async () => {
    controller = new AbortController();
    const requestOptions: RequestInit = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: myHeaders,
      redirect: "follow",
      signal: controller.signal,
    };

    statsDispatch({ type: dispatch, isLoading: true });
    try {
      const res = await fetch(newUrl.href, requestOptions);
      setStatus(res);
      const json = await res.json();
      statsDispatch({ type: dispatch, data: json });
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
    } finally {
      statsDispatch({ type: dispatch, isLoading: false });
    }
  };

  const abortFetch = () => {
    controller && controller.abort();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [abortFetch]);

  return [fetchData, isLoading, abortFetch, error, status];
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you define `controller` can go stale because each update it is re-assigned so instead use `useRef` so that it persists and holds reference to the original value across updates. Also that useEffect is missing the `fetchData` dependency and I don't see where or if `abortFetch` is ever called. Those are some reasons why it doesn't work. Here's my suggestions:

useRef for the controller:

```
  const controllerRef = useRef();
  const fetchData = async () => {
    controllerRef.current = new AbortController();
    const controller = controllerRef.current;
    const requestOptions: RequestInit = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: myHeaders,
      redirect: "follow",
      signal: controller.signal
    };
   // function body
  };

  const abortFetch = () => {
    controllerRef.current && controllerRef.current.abort();
  };
```

Move cancellations into fetchData:

If you want to ensure that calling `fetchData` cancels the previous `fetchData` consider adding the `abortFetch` into the first line of `fetchData` so that before it attempts to fetch anything, whatever currently is in progress is cancelled.

```
 const fetchData = async () => {
    // cancel anything if it exists
    controllerRef.current && controllerRef.current.abort();
    controllerRef.current = new AbortController();
     // function body 
 }
```

The `fetchData` should then look like this:

```
  const controllerRef = useRef();
  const fetchData = async () => {
    controllerRef.current && controllerRef.current.abort();
    controllerRef.current = new AbortController();
    const controller = controllerRef.current;
    const requestOptions: RequestInit = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: myHeaders,
      redirect: "follow",
      signal: controller.signal
    };

    statsDispatch({ type: dispatch, isLoading: true });
    try {
      const res = await fetch(newUrl.href, requestOptions);
      setStatus(res);
      const json = await res.json();
      statsDispatch({ type: dispatch, data: json });
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
    } finally {
      statsDispatch({ type: dispatch, isLoading: false });
    }
  };
```

Wrap the functions you return from the `useFetchStats` (`fetchData` and `abortFetch`) in `useCallbacks` so that they're always up to date:

```
  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    // function body
  }, [newUrl.href, statsDispatch]);

  const abortFetch = useCallback(() => {
    controllerRef.current && controllerRef.current.abort();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I can see this is a safer way to cancel the request. My only issue is when the function cancels a request the loading state is set to false and doesn't get set back to true when the function starts again. Is there a way I can guarantee that it gets set to true?